# Error in Installing cplexAPI on R studio

Tags: r, cplex

I am having an error in installing the following CPLEX package in R.

```
install.packages('cplexAPI')
```

It shows that

```
 Installing package into ‘/home/nomani/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cplexAPI_1.3.3.tar.gz'
 Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 404918 bytes (395 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 395 KB

* installing *source* package ‘cplexAPI’ ...
** package ‘cplexAPI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for cplex... NONE
configure: error: CPLEX interactive optimizer not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘cplexAPI’
* removing ‘/home/nomani/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/cplexAPI’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘cplexAPI’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpBEFSoC/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to change the R directory also but it didn't work. 
Just for information, I have installed CPLEX Free Trial Academic Version.

Comment: You could try adding the cplex bin directory (the location where the CPLEX interactive lives) to your PATH before installing. For example, if <COSDIR> is the location where CPLEX Optimization Studio is installed, then running the following from the command line should do the trick: `$ export PATH=$PATH:<COSDIR>/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux`.